# How to marshal the multi byte character set C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling

I need to call a function (c/c++) that uses the multi-byte character set from C#. But I don't know how to marshall it as multi-byte. Does anyone know how to convert the result to a string?

C#:

```
[DllImport("essentials.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern System.IntPtr GetFiles(string filedir, string path);

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            string filedir = @"C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\School\*";
            string path = @"C:\Users\Ruben\Documents\School\";
            System.IntPtr pointer = GetFiles(filedir, path);
            string files = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pointer); // nothing
        }
```

C++

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) char* GetFiles(char* filedir, char* path)
    {
        string filedir2 = filedir;
        string path2 = path;
        string files = GetFiles2(filedir2, path2);
        char* Rfiles = new char[files.length() + 1];
        strcpy_s(Rfiles, files.length() + 1, files.c_str());
        return Rfiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to debug your native code.  One explanation is that the string is simply empty.  You cannot pinvoke this code, the char[] you allocate can't be deleted again.

Answer (score 0):

Information on MSDN : [Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need the marshal the C# string first, try this:

```
[DllImport("essentials.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern System.IntPtr GetFiles
        ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]string filedir,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]string path);
```